# Максимальная непрерывная сумма в двоичном дереве за N переходов

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, теория

Дано двоичное дерево, со значениями весов перехода.
Нужно получить максимальное значение за N переходов начиная с нулевого узла. При этом путь должен быть непрерывный,с бесплатными возвратами в родительский узел.

Мой текущий алгоритм:

1. Найти последний доступный узел(в котором количество ходов равно 0, либо отсутствуют дети).
2. Записать в массив текущее значение и количество доступных ходов(с учетом потомков).
3. Перейти в родительский узел, скопировать оба массива(если 2 потомка), либо 1 массив (1 потомок).
4. Повторять п.2-3 до возврата в корневой узел.
5. На основании массива в корневом узле (в котором находятся все
   возможные сочетания значений+ходов) найти максимальное значение.

Основные вопросы:

1. Существует ли лучший алгоритм?
2. Возможно ли оптимизировать данный алгоритм т.к. работает слишком
   долго и требует слишком много памяти?

Comment: уточните, найти путь из центра вниз (N+1 вершина) с максимальной суммой на рёбрах?

Comment: Да,но с бесплатным возвратом в родительский узел(что и является главной проблемой задачи) и путь должен быть непрерывным.

Comment: динамикой просчитайте (например F[u][l] - оптимальная сумма длинны l из вершины u). А потом используйте и какой-нибудь максимум поддерживать на пути вниз по каждому параметру. Это *скорее всего* можно сделать за N*S (S - размер дерева).

Comment: @pavel Если я правильно понял алгоритм следущий:для дерева с высотой N найти максимум для каждого уровня.Записать эти значения в массив.Затем в массиве в цикле до N/2(первое с последним и т.д.) сложить эти значения и выбрать из них максимальное.Все правильно понял?

Comment: нет, написал ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение за `N*S` памяти, `N*S*S` или `N*S*log S` времени. `S - размер дерева`.

Динамика `F[vert][size]` - оптимальный ответ если мы в поддереве вершины `vert` берём `size` элементов.

Для любого элемента `F[u][0] = 0`
Для листа на этом всё.

Для вершины псевдокод. (r - правый потомок, l - левый).

```
for (int i=0;i<min(N,l.size());i++)
  F[u][i+1] = F[l][i] + D[u][l];
for (int i=0;i<min(N,r.size());i++)
  F[u][i+1] = max(F[u][i+1],F[r][i] + D[u][l]);
for (int i=0;i<min(N-1,l.size());i++)
    for (int j=0; j < min(N-i-1,r.size()); j++)
          F[u][i+j+2] = max(F[u][i+j+2], D[u][l] + D[u][r] + F[l][i] + F[r][j]);
```

Как-то так.
Мы либо берём только с 1 поддерева элементы. Либо берём с 2, тогда перебираем сколько берём слева и сколько справа.

Ответ - значение в `F[root][N]`. Для ускорения вместо двойного цикла использовать `Быстрое преобразование Фурье (FFT)`.

Comment: Прошу поправить если что-то неправильно понял:
В каждом узле храним массив пары значений, состоящий из оптимального(максимального) значения ответа и соответствующее значение перехода.
Кол-во елементов в массиве равно кол-во детей+1.
Для каждого узла с M переходов находим оптимальное значение для каждого M-1 перехода и ,если значение M-1 перехода больше чем текущее записаное для M-1, записываем в массив на соответствующую позицию.
В итоге это выходит оптимизированный алгоритм, написаный мной вначале, т.к. хранятся только оптимальные значения для каждого узла , а не все возможные?

Comment: примерно так, только размер осторожно. Там размер всего поддерева (а не кол-во детей). Значение перехода я храню отдельно и оно и так есть по условию. Если нужно восстановить ответ то лучше использовать обратный шаг а не хранить переход. Собственно алгоритм может и выглядит как оптимизированный но это сравнение неполимиального брутфорса и динамики.

Comment: Можно вопрос про конкретную реализацию на С?  Сам код http://pastebin.com/nK8UpMeF (оставил только структуру ноды и функцию , ненужное удалил).Сейчас максимальный прямой путь(т.е. переход с родителя в потомка) считает правильно, но отсутствует возврат в родительскую ноду.Предположительно из-за отсутствия двойного цикла т.к. не знаю как его реализовать на данных узлах.Пробовал сделать рекурсивно, но не вышло.В конструкторе узлов первым узлом всегда добавляет левый узел(т.е. left!=NULL && right==NULL значит узел с 1 потомком и предком).

Comment: ну собственно да. А что именно не получилось? Код в целом рабочий прямо в ответе. В ваших обозначения вместо `F[u][X] ---> curr->res[X] или curr->letf->res[X]` а где у вас вес `ребра` хранится я не понял...

Comment: Проще показать на рисунке - http://imgur.com/OGrjHUg .Сейчас я получаю синий путь вместо зеленого.Синий путь неправильный т.к. не максимальный и не использует все переходы(только 7 вместо 10).В итоге я получаю *прямой* путь, вместо путя с поворотами(не знаю как это объяснить лучше).Вес ребра хранится в value.В res хранится массив оптимальных значений для N+1 значений(turns это количество переходов)..

Comment: Из того,что как я думаю не вышло, это получение оптимального значения для узла с 2 потомками(left!=NULL && right!=NULL) т.к. у вас оно записано несколько непонятно.Я как-бы понимаю что это сравнение всех узлов слева и справа, но как это сделать у меня - не совсем понимаю.Пробовал рекурсивно вызывать данную функцию, но не вышло, результат был хуже чем сейчас.Скидываю весь код с текстом данного теста(http://pastebin.com/ABQR7ssr).Дерево ,несмотря на вводные данные, строится нормально.Ошибка в самой функции getMax

Comment: Переписал функцию сначала и получил http://pastebin.com/yGg1d8d0 .Тут она выдает результат через раз - иногда больше,иногда меньше.

Comment: так у вас что цена вершины а не ребра? ну тогда чуть поменяйте инициализацию - Во все дописывайте значение в текущем.

Comment: Вес ребер родитель-потомок я храню в потомке, разве так нельзя делать?Переписал в таком виде http://pastebin.com/nJERx3LK ., сейчас ошибка возникает в строке 62.В отличии от написанного вами в коментарии сменил с +2 на +1 чтобы не выходило за границу массива.Но сейчас стабильно считает ниже чем должно быть, можете что-то посоветовать или указать на ошибку?

Comment: случай с i=j=0 у вас какой-то очень странный. Если там по 0, то мы вообще ничего не берём. А вы для 1 пересчёт сделали. Конечно не влияет но всё же. А в 62 строке. Мы перебираем значение слева и справа. По логике, раз вы так пишешете, то значение в `i+j` а не `i+j+1` писать надо.

Comment: Касательно i=j=0 согласен.Но касательно i+j не согласен, т.к. мы  всегда записываем в +1 ячейку и т.к. тратим по 1 переходу на правый и левый узел а значит нужно писать i-1\j-1.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно ответ,возможно пригодится кому-то:
В дереве всегда добавляю сначала левую ноду , затем правую(см. if(left!=NULL & right==NULL).

```
void getMax(Node *curr,int turns)
{
    int i,j;
    if(curr->left!=NULL && turns!=0)
        getMax(curr->left,turns-1);
    if(curr->right!=NULL && turns!=0)
        getMax(curr->right,turns-1);
    curr->res=new int[turns+1]();
    curr->res[0]=0;
    if(curr->left==NULL && curr->right==NULL || turns==0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<turns+1;i++)
        curr->res[i]=0;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(curr->left!=NULL && curr->right==NULL)
        {
            Node*next=curr->left;
            for(i=0;i<turns;i++)
            {
                curr->res[i+1]=next->res[i]+next->value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                Node *left=curr->left;
                Node *right=curr->right;
                for(i=0;i<turns+1;i++)//left
                {
                    for(j=0;j<turns+1-i;j++)//right
                    {
                            if(i==0 && j==0)
                            {
                                curr->res[0]=0;
                            }
                            if(i==0 && j>=1)
                            {
                                curr->res[j]=max(curr->res[j],right->value+right->res[j-1]);
                            }
                            if(i>=1 && j==0)
                            {
                                curr->res[i]=max(curr->res[i],left->value+left->res[i-1]);
                            }
                            if(i>=1 && j>=1)
                            {
                                curr->res[i+j]=max(curr->res[i+j],left->value+right->value+left->res[i-1]+right->res[j-1]);
                            }

                    }
                }
    }
}
}
```

и сам класс

```
class Node
{
public:
Node *parent;
Node *left;
Node *right;
int id;
int value;
int *res;};
```